# React Native Review Prompt with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, native, review

I'm trying to trigger a review prompt at various places throughout our react native app. To trigger the prompt I use this bit of code.

```
StoreReview.requestReview()
```

Before I trigger the prompt I need to perform some logic. Pulling various information from a database and performing checks.

My question is, where is the best place to put this logic in a compartmentalized and reusable way so that I can use it throughout the app.

Could I use redux actions and middleware to trigger it on a state change?

Just put it in a utility file and import it, calling it like a normal function? The issue with this approach is I would want to trigger it when the user is done using a component. When to show the prompt relies more on state rather than any component.

Create some sort of react component, using react-navigation to show?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a component and call it conditionally inside of App.js or index.js
and whenever you want to turn it on you can just change the property using an action in Redux